# How to resolve Cannot find an overload for "add" and the argument count: "0".?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

I am trying to add items to a sharepoint 2013 list like this,$new is a collection of items:

```
foreach ($si in $new) 
        {
            $newItem = $listItems.add() 
            $newitem["Title"] = $si.NewTopics
            $newitem.update() 
        }
```

When I run this I am getting an error:

```
Cannot find an overload for "add" and the argument count: "0".
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you use

```
$newItem = $list.Items.Add()

#additional tweaks here
#$newItem["SomeField"] = "SomeValue"

$newItem.Update()
```

This should work, unless there is something wrong with your collection.

```
$list.Items.Add

OverloadDefinitions
-------------------
Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem Add()
Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem Add(string folderUrl,
Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileSystemObjectType underlyingObjectType, string
leafName)
Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem Add(string folderUrl,
Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileSystemObjectType underlyingObjectType)
```